# Ошибка при создании репозитория (spring data)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

**Имеется такая таблица:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

**В программе `spring data` и `postgres` подключаю в `pom` таким образом:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Модель таблицы выше:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Пробема возникается при добавлении в проект такого репозитория:**

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Что я делаю не так (`datasource` задан) ?

Comment: включите логирование и посмотрите, какие бины есть, а каких нет.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки покажите.